# PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_SODA_ADMIN.DESCRIBE_COLLECTION' must be declared

Tags: java, oracle, oracle12c, soda

I am using [SODA for Java](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56351_01/doc.30/e58124/soda_for_java.htm#ADSDA107) to store and retrieve documents from oracle 12c DB.
I am following this [example](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsondb/oracle-rdbms-as-a-nosql-json-document-store).

I am getting exception after the execution of the code.

> oracle.soda.rdbms.impl.SODAUtils$1OracleSQLException
>       at oracle.soda.rdbms.impl.SODAUtils.makeExceptionWithSQLText(SODAUtils.java:112)
>       at oracle.soda.rdbms.impl.SODAUtils.makeExceptionWithSQLText(SODAUtils.java:75)
>       at oracle.soda.rdbms.impl.OracleDatabaseImpl.loadCollection(OracleDatabaseImpl.java:1338)
>       at oracle.soda.rdbms.impl.OracleDatabaseImpl.openCollection(OracleDatabaseImpl.java:410)
>       at oracle.soda.rdbms.impl.OracleDatabaseImpl.createCollection(OracleDatabaseImpl.java:348)
>       at oracle.soda.rdbms.impl.OracleDatabaseImpl.createCollection(OracleDatabaseImpl.java:332)
>       at oracle.soda.rdbms.impl.OracleDatabaseImpl.createCollection(OracleDatabaseImpl.java:321)
>       at oracle.soda.rdbms.impl.OracleDatabaseImpl.access$100(OracleDatabaseImpl.java:62)
>       at oracle.soda.rdbms.impl.OracleDatabaseImpl$OracleDatabaseAdministrationImpl.createCollection(OracleDatabaseImpl.java:1798)
>       at com.cisco.salesconnect.lms.TestSoda.main(TestSoda.java:26)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
>   PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_SODA_ADMIN.DESCRIBE_COLLECTION' must be declared
>   ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:204)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1041)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1329)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3685)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4714)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1376)
>       at oracle.soda.rdbms.impl.OracleDatabaseImpl.loadCollection(OracleDatabaseImpl.java:1317)
>       ... 7 more

**Java Code**

```
try(OracleConnection conn = (OracleConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(/*connection url*/)) {

        conn.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
        conn.setStatementCacheSize(50);

        OracleRDBMSClient cl = new OracleRDBMSClient();

        OracleDatabase db = cl.getDatabase(conn);

        db.admin().createCollection("MyFirstJSONCollection");

    } catch (SCExceptions | SQLException | OracleException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What will be the reason behind this exception?

Comment: Is the package [installed properly](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2142385_1.html), and has the user you are connected as been granted privileges on it - presumably via the SODA_APP role, if you haven't skipped any steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in the code which gets executed when you call `db.admin().createCollection("MyFirstJSONCollection");` a reference is being made to an object called `DBMS_SODA_ADMIN.DESCRIBE_COLLECTION` which does not exist in the database. You should check and see if the schema `DBMS_SODA_ADMIN` exists, and if there is an object called `DESCRIBE_COLLECTION` in that schema. One way to do that would be to execute a query such as

```
SELECT *
  FROM DBA_USERS u
  WHERE u.USERNAME = 'DBMS_SODA_ADMIN'

SELECT *
  FROM DBA_OBJECTS o
  WHERE o.OWNER = 'DBMS_SODA_ADMIN' AND
        o.OBJECT_NAME = 'DESCRIBE_COLLECTION'
```

If either is missing it indicates that the installation of the Soda database components was either not performed, or did not complete successfully. If these things do exist it indicates that the user your codes connects as does not have the permissions needed to access this object.

Comment: You've misread the error `PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_SODA_ADMIN.DESCRIBE_COLLECTION' must be declared`
The DBMS_SODA_ADMIN is not a user, but it is a package name and DESCRIBE_COLLECTION is a procedure name within that package.

Answer (score 3):

Did you grant SODA_APP role to the user under which you're creating the collection? e.g.:

grant SODA_APP to userNameHere;

The error you're getting would happen if you didn't.